# Howto use Google Analytics with a multi parameter search

Tags: search, web, google-analytics

I have to integrate GA in project which uses a multi parameter search which should be tracked in detail.

Imagine a web shop selling computers with the following choices (some of them are even multi-selects):

- RAM size
- Type of computer (e.g. laptop)
- Color
- ...

Using the Site-Search option in GA in conjunction with virtual pageviews it caught my eye that there is a **restriction, that you can only define 5 parameters**. This seems to me being a standard scenario but google search doesn't help me finding an answer.

**How would you implement/configure a multi search scenario like this in GA?**

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a hit-scoped [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) for each parameter (RAM, Type, Colour etc.). Then, when the search results are shown, you would push something like the following to the Google Tag Manager dataLayer:

```
dataLayer.push({'ram_size' : '8gb', 'type' : 'Laptop', 'Colour' : 'Grey'});
```

Then in GTM, you would need to set up a variable for each one of these and pass those variables to the GA page view tag in the custom dimensions section of the tag configuration.